# Sauce Connect: Too many active tunnels

Tags: travis-ci, saucelabs

Sometimes my Travis builds fail because there are too many active Sauce Connect tunnels. I tried limiting the number of concurrent builds on Travis to 5 (then 4...) but it still happens. I searched for the error message but couldn't find any useful results.

Here is an example: https://travis-ci.org/SEL-Columbia/dokomoforms/jobs/50537933

Is there a standard way to deal with this?

Comment: Are you systematically terminating your tunnels at the end of a test? If you have tunnels that "hang around" because they've not been terminated, then limiting to 5 or 4 most likely won't do it.

Comment: I think Travis takes care of it for you...

Comment: u can turn them off mnually: https://saucelabs.com/beta/tunnels. Tho I think travis or saucelab should do that automatically.

Answer (score 0):

This actually is not a Travis problem. Sauce is throttling the Tunnels. Your license with Sauce will determine how many concurrent tunnels you can have. But I do believe there is an upper limit. This actually could be a bug in the integration. Did you check your.travis.yml where the tunnel is created. What happens if you run without sauce connect?